# sent back to header2.php when trying to create a topic in my forum

Tags: php, css

I have tried most of the youtube videos based on how to create a php forum but there are always problem with it.... Just recently, I have tried a forum from this youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IU_gFh4ZRBU&t=832s

But, in the forum_main.php page, whenever I tried to create a topic, it will take me back to header2.php for some unknown reason.....`

```
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PianoCourse101 Forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>
<center>
   <div id="holder">

      <div id="userInfo">
      <?php



     $action = $_GET['act'];


$actions_array = array('forum','create', 'topic', 'reply');

         if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?forum_main=notlogin'>"; 
             exit();
         } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = ?;";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
           echo "SQL error";
        } else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['u_uid']);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


         }


     }

     if ($resultCheck == 0) {
             session_destroy();
             echo "<div class='forum_main_welcome'>Please <a href=\"./includes/login.php\">Login</a> to your account, or <a href=\"./signup.php\">Register</a> a new account \n</div>";
          } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            echo "<div class='forum_main_welcome'><p class='forum_main_title'>Welcome to the Music Forum,</p><a href=\"./forum_main.php?act=profile&id=".$row['user_id']."\"><p class=\"forum_main_name\">".$row['user_uid']."</p></div></a>!";
            echo "<br>\n";
            echo "<div class='forum_main_welcome2'><a href=\"./forum_main.php?act=".$row['user_uid']."\">Forum Index |</a></div>\n";

            if($row['admin'] == 1) {
              echo "<div class='forum_main_welcome3'><a href=\"./administrator.php?act=".$row['user_uid']."\">Administrative Section</a></div>\n";
            }  else {
               echo "<div class='forum_main_welcome'>Please <a href=\"./login.php\">Login</a> to your account or <a href=\"./signup.php\"register a new account\n</div>";
          }
             $admin_user_level = $row['admin'];



            }




      ?>

      </div>
        <div id="content">
           <?php 
              if ($row['admin'] == 1) {

              } if(!$action || !in_array($action, $actions_array)) {
                $admin = $admin_user_level+1;

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE admin < ?;";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
               echo "SQL error";
            } else {
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $admin);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
              $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
              $i = 1;
              if ($resultCheck2 > 0) {
              $i++;
              while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                echo "<div id=\"fcontent\">\n";
                echo "<div class=\"header\" id=\"header_".$i."\" onMouseOver=\"this.className='headerb'\" onMouseOut=\"this.className='header'\">".$row2['name']."</div>\n";
                    $id = $row2['id'];
                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM forum_sub_cats WHERE cid = ? and admin < ".$admin_user_level."+1;;";

                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
              if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                 echo "SQL error";
              } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
                  echo "<div id=\"content\">\n";
                  echo "<a href=\"./forum_main.php?act=forum&id=".$row3['id']."\">".$row3['name']."</a>\n";
                  echo " ".$row3['des']."\n";
                  echo "</div>\n";
                }

                echo "</div>\n";
                    $i++;
              } 
              } 
          }

      } 


      } else {
           if ($action == 'forum') {
               include_once 'forum2.php';
           }

           if ($action == 'create') {
               include_once 'create.php';
           }

           if ($action == 'topic') {
               include_once 'topic.php';
           }

           if ($action == 'reply') {
              if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
                 header("Location: index.php");
              } else {
                   include_once 'reply.php';
              }

            }

            $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin = ?;";

            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql4)) {
               echo "SQL error";
            } else {
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $admin);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
              $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

           if ($row4['admin'] == 0) {


               if(!$action || !in_array($action, $actions_array)) {
                $admin2 = 0;

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM forum_cats WHERE admin = ?;";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
               echo "SQL error";
            } else {
               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $admin2);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
              $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
              if ($resultCheck2 > 0) {
              $i++;
              while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                echo "<div id=\"fcontent\">\n";
                echo "<div class=\"header\" id=\"header_".$i."\" onMouseOver=\"this.className='headerb'\" onMouseOut=\"this.className='header'\">".$row2['name']."</div>\n";
                    $id = $row2['id'];
                    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM forum_sub_cats WHERE cid = ? and admin = ?;";

                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
              if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
                 echo "SQL error";
              } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $id, $admin2);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
                  echo "<div id=\"content\">\n";
                  echo "<a href=\"./forum_main.php?act=forum&id=".$row3['id']."\">".$row3['name']."</a>\n";
                  echo "".$row3['des']."\n";
                  echo "</div>\n";
                }

                echo "</div>\n";
                    $i++;
              } 
              } 
          }

      } 
    }
  }
}
}






`
```

Comment: The first place you should look when your code does not behave as you expect (after checking the code itself) is in your log files. Your session isn't working. Unfortunately you did not provide a MVCE, and the code you posted above is incomplete. But the most likely is cause is that you either didn't call session_start() or did so after the headers had been sent.

Comment: thanks and I am getting a lot of undefined variables... am trying to do my own forum if possible.. cheers!